# Java generics - special case of extended and super usage

Tags: java, generics, extends, super

Is there any conceptual difference between these two methods?

```
public static <T> void add1(final Collection<T> drivers, final Collection<? super T> persons) {
    persons.addAll(drivers);    
}
```

and

```
public static <T> void add2(final Collection<? extends T> drivers, final Collection<T> persons) {
    persons.addAll(drivers);    
}
```

The following main method compiles without any warnings and executes without any runtime-exceptions. And the result is the expected one - 4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Person person1 = new Person();
    final Person person2 = new Person();
    final Collection<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(person1);
    persons.add(person2);

    final Driver driver1 = new Driver();
    final Collection<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>();
    drivers.add(driver1);

    add1(drivers, persons);
    add2(drivers, persons);

    System.out.println(persons.size());
}
```

I am aware of PECS principle, and since `persons` in the first method is a consumer, `super` should be use, respectively - `extends` should be used for `drivers` in the second method. But is there any gotchas? Any difference that I may miss? If not, which one of the versions is preferred, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the type that is inferred for `T`: in `add1` it is the component type of the first collection (`Driver`), in `add2` it's the component type of the second collection (`Person`).

In this case `T` is not used in the method body, so there's no visible difference.

Answer (score 2):

If A is a supertype of B, then B extends A, so there is no difference between the two versions.

Note that you can also use both `super` and `extends`:

```
public static <T> void add3(final Collection<? extends T> drivers, final Collection<? super T> persons) {
    persons.addAll(drivers);    
}
```